# GCP VPC peering active but ping fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

I have 2 GCP projects with 2 different VPCs:

1. VPC1 has the default subnet
2. VPC2 has a default subnet and a custom subnet

I then have 2 instances, one in each project:

1. instance1 has one network interface to VPC1 default subnet (internal IP 10.128.0.2)
2. instance2 has 2 network interfaces to:

   a) VPC2 default: default 10.128.0.1 (not a problem since default is not peered)

   b) VPC2 custom: custom 10.230.0.3 (the one peered)

Subnets are existing in the right regions and IP Ranges are not overlapping.
VPC Peering on the VPC1default to VPC2custom is active and routes have been exported/imported.

Both instances are in regions covered by the regional subnets declared in the VPC peering.

However, when I try to ping using the internal IP from one instance to another, it times out.
From 10.128.0.2, ping 10.230.0.3

What am I missing?

EDIT: Firewall rules are updated to allow all ports from both VPC IP Ranges.
I popped up instance3 in VPC2 to check if it could be firewall or DHCP because of second network interface. Instance3 is configured the same way as instance2, ie 2 subnets, default and custom.
I manage to make both instance communicate without issues... but still can't communicate with any of these 2 from the other peered VPC

Comment: Check the firewall rules for both the VPC and the OS internal firewall. ICMP needs to be enabled for both VPC address ranges.

Comment: thanks, I've allowed internal for all ports, including icmp, for both projects and address ranges, but still times out

Comment: Did you check the OS internal firewall rules (iptables)?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed, IMO it is very releavnt. I ran into the same issue. The problem is that a second NIC is not routable by default on GCP and all traffic is by default sent to the first NIC. You need to explicitly add routes to the second NIC e.g. `ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 via 10.10.11.1  dev ens5` where 172.0.16.0/24 is the network you want to reach, 10.10.11.1 is the gateway on the network of the second NIC and ens5 is the name of the seconf interface.